# Is key-value store database a good option for full-text search storage?

Tags: full-text-search, nosql, cassandra, redis, riak

Would it be a good option to use key-value store database like cassandra and riak for storing your texts, which will be used for full-text search? If it is not recommendable, what are the reason for not going this path? Anybody has any experience on using key-value store for full-text search store?

Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that I recommend you to look at tjake's excellent project called [Lucandra](http://github.com/tjake/Lucandra) (Lucandra - A Cassandra Backend for Lucene/Solr)

Answer (score 3):

Riak also has the [Riak Search](http://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Riak+Search) feature.